# Formatting not working unless sheet is activated

Tags: vba, formatting, runtime

The code below works fine, but if I comment out the `Worksheets(Options).Activate` line, I get run-time error 1004.  Does anyone have any idea why this is?

```
        Worksheets(Options).Activate
        Worksheets(Options).Range(Cells(OptCurrentRow, 1), Cells(OptCurrentRow, OptEndCol)).Font.Bold = True
        Worksheets(Options).Range(Cells(OptCurrentRow, 1), Cells(OptCurrentRow, OptEndCol)).Interior.Color = LongColor
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that in order to use the range object for a worksheet the range needs to be on the active worksheet. The following code refers to cells and should work regardless of which worksheet is active, keeping the other variables from your origonal post.

```
    Dim iColumnCounter As Integer

    For iColumnCounter = 1 To OptEndCol
        With Worksheets(options).Cells(OptCurrentRow, iColumnCounter)
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Interior.Color = LongColor
        End With
    Next iColumnCounter
```